# Nuget Package download count

Tags: xml, api, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to add a count of a number of times a particular package was downloaded to my page. I'm only interested in a single package.
I understand I can make a call to `http://www.nuget.org/packages/[packageId]`, parse the page and get to the count this way, but this is quite troublesome.

I saw [this](http://elegantcode.com/2011/09/27/whats-happening-on-the-nuget-feed-leveraging-odata-in-an-rss-reader/), but could not figure out how to construct a url to get xml feed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by this: [UsingOdataWithTheNugetApi](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/15/using-odata-with-the-nuget-api/)

Comment: The link is down... Do you still have the example code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show count on HTML UI just use badges. You can crate many types of them e.g. with: [shields.io](https://shields.io/)

[Downloads count badge](https://shields.io/category/downloads) example:
[image: NuGet Downloads]

[Nuget version badge](https://shields.io/category/version) example: [image: Package Version]

Badges are very popular now you can use them to show Build and unit tests results, package version, download count, rating, analytics, etc... You can see many examples on [Github docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/Modal.md).